# Vanity URLs using PHP and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am developing an app using PHP and I would like my users to be able to use their own vanity URLs.

In this format:

`http://example.com/username`

For example:

`http://example.com/myCoolUsername`

If I use this URL now the server thinks it is a folder but I know I should use a .htaccess file in a way but I do not know what content I should use in that file.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule will rewrite `http://domain.com/username` to `user.php` with `username` as GET parameter (`name`).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user.php?name=$1
```

To test, create a file named `user.php` in your directory root ant put that in your file:

Access `http://domain.com/blablaName123` and if everything works fine you should see `string(13) "blablaName123"`

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your `index.php` receives a `$_GET['username']` to map to their vanity URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Make sure you only match on files/directories that don't actually exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite the first part after the `/` into a `username` parameter
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```